# How to deploy keycloak as a pod in kubernetes dashboard which is set up up in AWS EC2?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, keycloak

Added from a form which is `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak`

Changed from Loadbalancer to a Nodeport

Can visit that but ip:port

Showing error to add a user from localhost:8080 or use add-user-keycloak script

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://www.keycloak.org/documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the docs [Keycloak on Kubernetes](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-kube).

You can find instructions there, how deploy keycloak inside minikube.
However you can download this deployment files and modify the settings according to your needs.

F.E. you can change service type from `Loadbalancer` to `NodePort`.

In addition please consider making a changes in other settings like: `KEYCLOAK_USER`, `KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD`:

```
wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/latest/kubernetes-examples/keycloak.yaml | \
sed "s/LoadBalancer/NodePort/" | \
kubectl create -f -
```

In order to access your keycloak instance you should change:

- minikube ip ( to your externalIp address associated with your vm or use nodeIP from inside the vm)
- verify your service NodePort by running.

```
    kubectl get services/keycloak -o go-template='{{(index .spec.ports 0).nodePort}}'
    kubectl get svc -o wide
```

By default NodePort should be in the range  [(30000-32767)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)

Comment: im not running in minikube thats the issue, running on kubectl... after many digging i came up with a fix. thank you

Comment: what that means `running on kubectl...` the process should be similar one difference is to verify your `Node_IP` and `Node_Port`. So please share with your solution.

Comment: so what i did was `kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/latest/kubernetes-examples/keycloak.yaml`

after that went to services changed from `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort`

thats it